# Reset password issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

im having a strange issue in my reset password, basically in the for first gave me a error when i submitted saying the passwords is required, so the i notice in the ResetsPassword.php i had the code: 'passwords' => 'required|confirmed|min:6', with a 's', after i fix it in the input name, now is giving me another strange error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password_confirmation' in 'where clause'`

Does Laravel 5.2 have any issues with the resets form?

Comment: The error is basically saying that the `password_confirmation` column doesn't exit in the table you are querying. Have you checked your table and verified that it does exist?

Comment: Instead of comparing the `password_confirmation` input,  add `|confirmed` to the end of your `passwords` rule.

Comment: Is your database setup correctly?

Comment: I guess there isn't any issue with password reset since I'm using it and its working fine. Also, which file did you change ? As far as I know `ResetPassword.php` is a trait and it resides `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth` which is not meant to be changed.
Can you check `config/auth.php` file ?